# Automatically reloading variable state into GHCi when re-loading a file

Tags: haskell, emacs, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

When I'm developing some data analyses pipelines in haskell, it often would be useful to preload variable state into GHCi upon loading.

What I end up doing now is copy and pasting parts of a script line-by-line in emacs just to test and check the output of some intermediate processing. I can't even bulk copy-paste code because the line breaks don't get transferred (at least in emacs Interactive-Haskell mode)

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: simply loading/reloading a .hs file doesn't do the trick because afaik there's no way to have "<-" bindings at the top level.

Comment: why not make it into a function/expression and load it? Or pack it up into a normal module and just load it into ghci?

Comment: because i want to use ghci to do interactive analysis/testing with variables within the function.

Comment: can you give an example? I don't think I understand correctly - normally you can pack everything you use into a .hs file and just load it into ghci

Comment: that may work for pure code - I could have a "pseudo-script" where I strip off "let" statements from the equivalent code within a do block. How would  I deal with impure code which has bindings, for example with "<-"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. But anything that you can type into GHCi, you can also put into a file called `.ghci` in the current directory and it will run automatically anytime you launch GHCi. Does that help you?

Comment: conceptually, it would be useful to interact with variables as if I'm within the do block of main. Loading .ghci files works. If that's the best approach, please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be possible to do something nice with Template Haskell here, to make it easier to dump local variables to a temporary file and then read that file in, but I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at [foreign-store](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foreign-store-0.2/docs/Foreign-Store.html). It allows you to refer to variables by numbers, which persists through reloads. Here is an example:

```
λ: :set -XScopedTypeVariables 
λ: import Foreign.Store
λ: st <- newStore "example"
Loading package foreign-store-0.2 ... linking ... done.
λ: readStore st
"example"
λ: st
Store 0
λ: :r
Ok, modules loaded: none.
λ: st
<interactive>:8:1:
    Not in scope: ‘st’
    Perhaps you meant ‘fst’ (imported from Prelude)
λ: Just (st :: Store String) <- lookupStore 0
λ: readStore st
"example"
```

Alternatively, you can also put all your definitions in a single hs file and only reload that. You can use unsafePerformIO to get around the restriction that you cannot use `<-` at the top-level. I think that is ok in this case, since your only using it for interactive anyway:

```
module Example where

import System.IO.Unsafe

example :: String 
example = "example"

file :: String
file = unsafePerformIO $ readFile "/tmp/example.hs"
```

Comment: Yes, I just use `unsafePerformIO` for this purpose. The disadvantage is that the variable has to be recomputed on every reload; if computing it is quite expensive then the foreign-store approach might be better.

Comment: @ReidBarton Yes, you can even combine unsafePerformIO with foreign-store: create a foreign store, perform the expensive operation, and use unsafePerformIO to do the lookupStore in the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this:

- Use the `:l [filename]` GHCi command to reload a file without exiting GHCi.
- Write the variables in your `~/.ghci` file, which will be loaded when GHCi is opened.

If you don't know what to put into `~/.ghci`, here's what I have in mine:

```
:set prompt "\955 "
:set prompt2 "| "

:def hoogle \x -> return $ ":!hoogle --info \"" ++ x ++ "\""

let f `on` x = \a b -> (f a) `x` (f b)
let break (f,g) = \a -> (f a, f g)
```

Comment: reloading a file doesn't do the trick. I can't do bindings in the top level with "<-" as far as I can tell. .ghci files work. one interesting thing I noticed with emacs is I can have any file with a .ghci extension (e.g. currWork.ghci), load it into the interpreter via C-c and C-l and it works like a script that's copy-pasted. This way I can have little interactive state-loaders on a per-task basis (rather than dumping everything into a single globally-used .ghci file).

Comment: `<-` does work in interactive mode. For example: you can type `str <- getLine` in ghci and it will run `getLine` and bind whatever you type to `str`